# How to accomplish the following combination in a grammar?

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

I would like to set a rule that I can have an expression that starts with a non-reserved word, but it can contain a path that can contain a reserved word. Examples would be:

```
myFunc().select
table.select.select.myFunc().array[0].select
new.select.test
```

My thinking was to use a rule like this:

```
exprWithoutReservedKeyword (DOT exprWithReservedKeyword)*
```

However, this seems like it would be incredibly repetitious, if for example the `expr` rule had 30 alternatives, such as:

```
expr:
    OPEN_PAREN expr CLOSE_PAREN
    | selectStatement
    | ...
```

So then how would I accomplish that, would I have to re-write (i.e., copy-paste) the entire expression two times and then one time I would add in the `reservedKeyword` rule? And if both are recursive, wouldn't there be incredible ambiguity competing between those two rules? What would be a good way to handle it?

Or would I need to basically make each of the sub-expressions non-recursive and handle that in the parent, such as:

```
expr:
    exprWithoutReservedKeyword (DOT exprWithReservedKeyword)*
    | expr
    ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that somewhere in your `expr` rule (perhaps buried inside subrules), there will be something like:

```
path : IDENTIFIER
     | path '.' IDENTIFIER
```

You'll want to change that to

```
path : IDENTIFIER
     | path '.' (IDENTIFIER | reserved_word)
```

where `reserved_word` is defined somewhere as a conjunction of reserved word tokens, which is probably a long list.

In languages with "semi-reserved" words, you'll find other contexts in which some reserved words are possible, but not all of them; to handle those, you'll need other sets as well as `reserved_word`. That can get tedious, but fortunately you only need to do it once.

Note that `reserved_word` must be a non-terminal, not a token; if it were a token, it would be recognised unconditionally, but you only want it to be recognised in this particular context.

Comment: thanks, could you please explain what you mean by `Note that reserved_word must be a non-terminal, not a token; if it were a token, it would be recognised unconditionally, but you only want it to be recognised in this particular context.` ? What would be an example of how you would make it a non-terminal, not a token?

Comment: Now that I've seen your other question, it appears that you are already using this solution. It's certainly a bit clunky, but it's not really awful, and lots of grammars use it. The Lemon parser generator (which is probably not useful for you, because it only generates C code) was designed with SQL parsing in mind, and it has a way of declaring a "fallback" token type, so you can tell it, for example, that `SELECT` is a `TK_SELECT` but fall back to `IDENTIFIER` in a context where `TK_SELECT` isn't valid. That's a very handy feature which few other parser generators implement.

Comment: @samuelbrody1249: If you called it `ReservedWord`, it would be a token. Calling it `reserved_word` makes it a non-terminal. That's how Antlr works. (I added that note because people often make single-word patterns into tokens when they should be non-terminals, and that leads to obscure parsing errors.)

Comment: right, it's kind of a "both and", `SELECT` can be a terminal and it can also be part of a 'path identifier', so for example: `SELECT myTbl.select` -- where it is recognized once as a terminal and once as part of a path (in this case, a field within `myTbl`).